# Solve for $x$ in $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}=a$. Why does Wolfram alpha use complex numbers here?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Is there any possible way of doing this without using complex numbers?

And why are complex numbers used?

Comment: Used by who? Could you explain what you are talking about? Who used complex numbers?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Flnx%3Da+solve+for+x

Comment: Put it in the question. Ask "why does Wolfram alpha use complex numbers?"

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following is a satisfying answer to you.

Whether or not you get complex solutions really depends on a. If some equation has only complex solutions and you want a solution you cannot get it while avoiding complex numbers.

If you look at the function, you'll see that for $0\leq x<1$  you'll only get non-positive values ranging from $0$ to $-\infty$ (not including $-\infty$ of course). For x=1 your function is undefined since $\log(1)=0$.

For $x>1$ you'll find that the minimum of $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ is $e$ for $x=e$.

For $x<0$ you don't get real values since $\log(x)$ is not a real number for $x<0$.

From that argument it is easy to see that for $0<a<e$ you won't get any solution with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. But for $a\leq 0$ you will find a solution $0\leq x<1$ and for $a\geq e$ you'll always find 2 real solutions with $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called the [Lambert $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which lets us solve equation line $ye^y=b$ - then $b=W(y)$.

The $W$-function also lets us solve $z\log z=b$, by letting $z=e^y$ and seeing that $ye^{y}=a$ so $y=W(a)$ and $z=e^{W(a)}$.

Now, in $\frac{x}{\log x}=a$, invert and set $z=x^{-1}$, then

$$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{\log x}{x}=-z\log z$$

So $z=e^{W(-1/a)}$ and $$x=\frac{1}{e^{W(-1/a)}}.$$

Nothing inherently about complex numbers, but the $W$ function does not always take real values. In particular, when $0<a<1$, we'd need $x<\log x$ for a real solution, which is not possible.

Wolfram Alpha also often looks for all the complex numbers by default. So even when there is only one real root, it might look for an expression for all complex roots.